# $h^k\,_i \: h^l\,_j\: g_{kl}$. Why can i permute $i$ and $k$ for $h$

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

> Let $f : U \rightarrow R^{m+1}$, $U \subset R^m$ open, be an immersion with Gauss map
> $\nu : U \rightarrow S^m$. Assuming that $\nu$ is an immersion, prove that :
>
> $$A(\nu) = \int_U|K|\sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} \:dx$$

For an immersion :
$$A(f) := \int_U \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})} \: dx$$

The notation is $h_{ij} = h^k\,_i \:g_{kj}$ where $h_{ij}$ is the second fundamental form, $h^k\,_i$ is $-d\nu$.

The solution is as follows.
$$\nu_i = h^k\,_i f_k $$ Therefore :
\begin{align*}
\langle\nu_i, \nu_j \rangle = \langle h^k\,_i f_k, h^l\,_j f_l \rangle = h^k\,_i \, h^l\,_j \; \langle  f_k, f_l \rangle =  h^k\,_i \, h^l\,_j \; g_{kl}
\end{align*}
Then, the solution does the following move :

> \begin{align} \label{move}
> h^k\,_i \: h^l\,_j\: g_{kl} = h^k\,_i \, g_{kl}\,  h^l\,_j = h^i\,_k \, g_{kl}\,  h^l\,_j
> \end{align}

So we get :

\begin{align*}
\det (\langle\nu_i, \nu_j \rangle)  = \det\left((h^i\,_k)_{ik} \circ (g_{kl})_{kl} \circ  \det(h^l\,_j)_{lj}\right) = K^2 \det(g_{kl})
\end{align*}
Yielding the desired result.

My problem is with the justification of the second move.

Now, here is my understanding of $h^k\,_i$:

$$h = h^k\,_i \: (e_k \otimes e^i) $$
$$h = h^i\,_k \: (e_i \otimes e^k) $$

I'm not sure how to understand the move...

Comment: Context? For one thing, the Einstein summation convention is violated with that move.

Comment: @TedShifrin is it better now ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a minus sign is missing in the equation for $\nu_i$; it won't matter because we're taking the inner product of two such expressions.

Second, their maneuver is not valid. The matrix $(h_i^k)$ is definitely not necessarily symmetric. However, let's understand this in matrix notation. If $G=(g_{k\ell})$ and $H=(h_i^k)$ are the square matrices, then the equation is
$$\langle \nu_i,\nu_j \rangle = (H^\top GH)_{ij},$$
and
$$\det(H^\top GH) = \det(H^\top)\det(G)\det(H) = \det(H)^2\det G = K^2\det G,$$
as needed.